# How long does it take for newly pushed files in GitHub reflected on GitHub API?

Tags: github, github-api

I am working with GitHub API and I am querying for a specific file. I am able to query specific filenames that have been over 24 hours in GitHub repo but I am unable to query newly pushed files on Github. My question is how long does it take for GitHub API to update and be able to show newly pushed files in its api?

Comment: Surely it'd be immediate?

Comment: It would be helpful if you supplied either the API call you are making or the code you are using to make it.

Comment: This is the api call I'm making https://api.github.com/search/code?q=org:Example+filename:example.txt

Comment: Oh you're searching, not querying a specific repo. Surely it's because github has to index the files?

Comment: I don't know why it's not getting the newly pushed files?

Comment: What do you mean GitHub has to index the files? Shouldn't the newly pushed files be indexed as soon as I pushes to the GitHub repo?

Comment: Actually, I figured out why. If I use the api call https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/content then I'm able to see the new files but I want to use the previous api call I mentioned to search all related filenames but the problem is the newly pushed files are not indexed for that api call? Why is that?